# Could not load assmebly, library reference versus main project

Tags: wpf, exception, reference, prism

I have a project that is made up of several other library projects and a main application (using Prism to build a composite application). I'm using Telerik.Reporting which uses Telerik.Windows.Controls in one of my application's libraries.

I'm getting an exception that it could not load the controls library

"Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Windows.Controls, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Telerik.Windows.Controls, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7"}"

If I reference Telerik.Windows.Controls in my main project, this error goes away. However, I do not understand why I would need to do this and I do not want to do this. I feel that it should not be necessary for my main project, which does not use any Telerik controls, to reference the telerik controls library just because it is using a library which uses the telerik controls.

**Is there a way to avoid having to reference the Telerik library in my main project which doesn't even use those controls?**

I tried added the library to the GAC but that did not help.In fact, it made it worse. I tried re-adding the libraries to the main project and got the same exception! I had to go unregister it with the GAC to make it work at all.

Comment: Is some other library that you're using referencing Telerik.Windows.Controls?

Comment: Yes my MainProject.exe references MyLibrary.dll which uses Telerik.ReportViewer which requires Telerik.Windows.Controls. I have MyLibrary->Telerik.Windows.Controls which I thought should work. But, it seems to require MainProject -> Telerik.Windows.Controls which I'm trying to avoid!